# как получить все отзывы для каждой модели в цикле ?Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

таблицы :

```
Profiles(id, user_id, name);
Reviews(id, user_id, name, body);
Users(id, name);
```

модель User имеет связь с Profile один ко одному

есть еще модель Review соответсвенно и таблица в БД в которой каждый отзыв привязывается к User через поле user_id

Вопрос как правильно прокрутить в цикле и получить доступ Reviews

```
@foreach($profiles as $profile)
   как сделать чтобы в $profile->получить (Reviews которые привязаны к user_id такому же как и текущий в цикле $profile ?
@endforeach

class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User
{
  public function profile() {
        return $this->hasOne(Painter::class);
    }
}
class Profile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    
    public function save(array $options = [])
    {
        // If no author has been assigned, assign the current user's id as the author of the post
        if (!$this->author_id && Auth::user()) {
            $this->user_id = Auth::user()->getKey();
        }

        return parent::save();
    }
}
```

спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не указали содержимое класса Review. 
Вообще, лично я вижу два пути:

1. В User добавить связь с Review. Дальше тупо дергать profile->user->review.
2. Связать Profile с Review через hasOneThrough и получать через profile->review.

   ```
    
    public function review()
        {
            return $this->hasOneThrough(
                Review::class,
                User::class
            );
        }
   ```